# viewDidLoad method and Notification center

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have two view controller.I need to update second view controller's ui from first.I put the this line inside the second view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "actOnSpecialNotification:", name: mySpecialNotificationKey, object: nil)
}
```

This is a tab system,first view controller is showing first tab and second view controller is showing second tab.

Here are some code:
[image]

And I got an exception here:
[image]

When the app launchs if user doesn't press the second tab `viewDidLoad` method is not calling and I can't update the ui.How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: are you using navigation controller to switch between the _first_ and _second_ view controller?

Comment: This is a tab system,I am using tab view controller.

Comment: oh I see, so literally the two view controllers are in the memory _at the same_ time...? so, how do you post the notification from the _first_ view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the observer in the controller's init method (or in awakeFromNib if the controller is coming out of a xib or storyboard). viewDidLoad is only called for the controller in the first tab when a tab bar controller first launches. viewDidLoad for the other controllers is not called until you click on their tab.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6j56f2 I am getting this. Code:http://prntscr.com/6j575i What is wrong ?

Comment: @Okan, you can't update your table if the controller's view has not been loaded yet, because that outlet will be nil. You can update messageString like you are, but the line to update the table should be removed from the notification's selector. Put that line in viewDidLoad instead.

Comment: Hmm,ok.But ı have a question to you.What is the best way to this ? It is same with whatsapp.Imagine it:In whatsapp,you are selecting a person from "Favorites" tab then whatsapp is adding this person to "chats" tab.I have to do same thing.User selects a person from first tab then I have to add this person to second tab.What do you suggest for this ?

Comment: @Okan, you can pass that person object to some property you have in the second controller just like you are for messageString. You can update any properties like that, you just can't update the UI until viewDidLoad.

Comment: @Okan, yes it's ok to use a notification for this purpose. You could also use delegation though. You could make the second controller the delegate of the first, and have the first controller send a message to its delegate any time it needs to update any information.